# %X format specifier to represent an integer

Tags: c

I've been taking a look a Zed A. Shaw's "Learn C the hard way" tutorials. One of his extra credit questions *(in exercise 9)* requested me to represent a `char[4]` as an `int`.

After scouting around I came over a SO question that was about the same thing and therefore managed to come up with the answer:

```
int i;
int intName = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    intName = intName + name[i];
}

printf("intName: %d\n", intName);
printf("intName: %X\n", intName);
```

---

Output:

```
intName: 291
intName: 123
```

---

The name at hand was, "Zed", I calculated the ASCII decimal values and they did indeed add up to 291, which is fine. However after searching I couldn't find any explanation as to why `%X` would return 123.

In this scenario, what does this format specifier do? It would be awesome if I were to get somewhat of a detailed answer as to what's going on. Learning C seems far more in-depth and I feel I should completely understand these basics such as these before moving on to anything else.

Comment: I don't think your solution is what the author of the problem had in mind. You're just adding the ordinal values of the characters, so for example `"Zed"` and `"edZ"` would yield the same result, as would many other combinations of different characters. I think you need to read the exercise more carefully. (I'm assuming the question itself is reasonably unambiguous, but I haven't checked.)

Comment: When printing a number in hexadecimal, it's often a good idea to precede it with `0x` or `0X` to make that clear to the reader (assuming the reader is somewhat knowledgeable about C syntax): `printf("intName: 0x%X\n", intName);`

Comment: @KeithThompson - I understand what you mean and it may be the case, the Extra Credits section is fairly vague and is mainly there to help you just explore things you wouldn't normally explore. If you wish check out Zed A. Shaw's tutorial Exercise 9 to get a better idea of what he's asking for. As far as your second comment goes, you're right, it's better practice to represent the hex with a 0x. Thanks!

Comment: The question he asked was as follows, "If an array of characters is 4 bytes long, and an integer is 4 bytes long, then can you treat the whole name array like it's just an integer? How might you accomplish this crazy hack?"

Comment: So he's talking about treating that 4-byte region of memory (defined as a `char[4]` array) *as if* it were a 4-byte integer. Adding the values of the bytes isn't the answer. (Pointer casts are one solution, but a 4-byte `char` array might not be aligned properly to hold a 4-bytes integer. I'd use `memcpy()` to copy the contents of the array into an integer object.) BTW, don't assume that "integer" means `int`; `int` is just one of several integer types.

Comment: Very well, thanks alot for the extra insight on the question Keith!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However after searching I couldn't find any explanation as to why %X would return 123.

It's just printing the hex representation of the number. Hex 123 = decimal 291. From a [`printf` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) (the first I happened to find):

> **o, u, x, X**
>   The unsigned int argument is converted to unsigned octal (o), unsigned decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal (x and X) notation. The letters abcdef are used for x conversions; the letters ABCDEF are used for X conversions. The precision, if any, gives the minimum number of digits that must appear; if the converted value requires fewer digits, it is padded on the left with zeros. The default precision is 1. When 0 is printed with an explicit precision 0, the output is empty.

Comment: Sigh, had to be something that simple.. Thanks alot Jon!